Devise Tiemout - Are cookies the only way of passing params after a timeout?
I can not believe it is not possible to pass parameters to Devise's timeout method... so I hope someone can enlighten me.
I have a Rails application with two mountable engines: A and B. Both engines share the same authentication system based on Devise. I also use the auto-session-timeout gem, overriding the active and timeout methods. When a timeout occurs and the timeout method is called, I need the following parameters to redirect to the correct page:

login_source: this is stored in the session and determines from which application the current user logged in (A or B).

customer': the name of the customer. Different customers have different stylesheets. This can be obtained from the current user.

location': which of the customer's locations was used. This can also be obtained from the current user.


When the timeout method is called in my sessions controller, the session has already been killed. This leaves me only one option: to store the parameters in the cookies and retrieve them from there to redirect to the correct login page.
Ideally, I would like to get these parameters from somewhere else, as cookies are being restricted more and more. In the future, if the site is embedded in an iframe, I won't even be able to get the parameters from the cookies, as they will be considered third-party cookies (Source).

Local storage is probably where you want to go. https://coryrosser.medium.com/local-storage-what-when-and-how-fb73c746391

Devise's timeout method - can you link to what method you're talking about

@Alex I forgot to mention that I also use  the auto-session-timeout gem in combination with Devise. This gem provides automatic session timeout in a Rails application. By overriding the timeout method, you can determine where an user is redirected to after the timeout. Unfortunately, when the timeout method is called, the session has already expired.

It's a bit clunky, but you can keep user session until timeout is called:
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  auto_session_timeout 30.seconds

  def handle_session_reset(c)
    # c.send :reset_session # don't reset session
  end
end

# app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def timeout
    # TODO

    sign_out
    flash[:notice] = t("devise.failure.timeout", default: "Your session has timed out.")
    redirect_to sign_in_path
  end

  def active
    response.headers["Etag"] = nil
    render plain: !session_expired?(self), status: 200
  end
end

https://github.com/pelargir/auto-session-timeout/blob/v1.1/lib/auto_session_timeout.rb

It seems that when working together with devise, auto_session_timeout works a bit different (Using with Devise). Currently I am configuring the timeout time in devise.rb:  config.timeout_in = 10.minutes.

Also the handle_session_reset doesn't seem to be called.

@pabvvv config.timeout_in = 10.minutes - that's a devise's Timeoutable module config, it's unrelated to this gem. handle_session_reset - it's right here, i don't see how it can be skipped.
